# Sending files from one webpage to another

Tags: java, php, servlets, server, client

So my project requires me to implement the following-

1. The client(called agent) requesting for a file.
2. The file distributor(called admin) getting the request from agent.
3. The file distributor then editing the file(a database/excel sheet) manually.
4. The file distributor sending this file to agent.

Consider user A wants file X(.csv). He requests for the same from the admin. Admin then checks the request and adds one extra entry into the file. He then sends the file X(+1 entry) to the user A. Wanted to know how to implement the admin sending the file part.
I want to implement the above without the use of e-mails. 
Thank you.

Comment: And how *do* you want to implement it? Why not have the admin save a file in a known location where the agents application will look for them? In any case, you'll need to do a much better job of explaining how you want it to work.

Comment: And, Your question is ? ;-)

Comment: Consider user A wants file X(.csv). He requests for the same from the admin. Admin then checks the request and adds one extra entry into the file. He then sends the file X(+1 entry) to the user A. Wanted to know how to implement the admin sending the file part.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a shared file in database (as blob type) or on server file system. 
Administrator via webpage can upload file (e.g. [file upload](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml)), where after persisting final version of file user should be informed.

As process is asynchronous, notification might be realized by:

- e-mail (easiest way)
- webpage (users have to open page to see them)
- websockets (enhanced version of webpage option)
- RSS feed

Comment: Is there a way to edit the file already stored on the database via PHP? Like adding an extra row to the excel file?

Comment: Yes, return file to the end user (select clause) and after retrieval, update given db table row by id (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)